Geometry Proximity node: Not scaling surrounding mesh evenly?
I divided a Cube in striped areas with different materials, with the center stripe beeing red. I want a scaling (along x axis) to affect all stripes, fading out the further away from the center.
I thought this node arrangement could be read as "scale all stuff around the red material"

But the scaling effect appearently only affects the red material.

Why is the width of the green and blue areas not changing at all?
File (Blender 4.2.2):


Use "Boolean Math: AND" not "Multiply". Your example is incomplete. The .blend file should be complementary so it's easier to play around with the project without recreating it from scratch, but the question should show full setup. If the setup is big - reduce it to be minimal. You're using a random node, so I don't see why you would expect consistency.

I updated the picture. boolean and multiply are identical here.

Yes, I simply mean the boolean math is more idiomatic and readable. The "only x direction" can be done by normal -> vector math: multiply <1, 0, 0>. Keep in mind because normals are normalized vectors, your vertices on top/bottom edges will have smaller x components, because the z component will steal from the x component. You don't show the "range" and "amplitude" inputs, and for the sake of an example you shouldn't even rely on inputs, just put them directly in the map range node. And again: you're using randomness, so of course the result is inconsistent.

And the green and blue areas do change - if they didn't, they would overlap the red that has moved.

the green and blue areas only get translated while the red one gets stretched though

Use a normalized 0..1 value as map range output, then raise it to some power, then use another map range to convert it to the desired output. Or use float curve.

how do i normalize a float map range output?

To min = 0, To max = 1, or vice-versa.
